# NativeScript Downloader plugin: Can not open zip file after downloading the file

Tags: nativescript, unzip, nativescript-plugin

I am working on native script 8 and using [ns plugin add @triniwiz/nativescript-downloader](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-downloader) plugin to download the zip file from the server.

I get the download response

```
"status": "completed",
"path": "file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.example/cache/1bbf6484-9c77-4357-9759-1c1a55011a21"
```

but when the plugin tries to unzip the same downloaded file it gives me this

```
File does not exist, invalid archive path: file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.example/cache/1bbf6484-9c77-4357-9759-1c1a55011a21
```

I am using @nativescript/zip for unzipping the downloaded file.

```
unZipFile(path, unzipPath) {
        let destination = fs.path.join(this.document.path,"/assets/",unzipPath);
        return Zip.unzip({
            archive: path,
            directory: destination,
            onProgress: this.onUnZipProgress
        }).then((res) => {
               console.log(res);
                return destination; 
        }).catch((err) => {
            return 'failed-----------------:'+err; 
        }); 
    }
```

not sure if there is something wrong with the code or the plugin, can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the download directory you're using. You likely should be using only the temp or documents known folders.  See the [NativeScript File System][1] docs for details.

I've seen a problem similar to this where it *looks* like the file downloaded successfully but in fact failed due to security restrictions.  This is especially true on iOS.
[1]: https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system